# Python 2.7 - iterate through a CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Afternoon,

I have the following Python 2.7 code below. I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Read a CSV file which contains values for the 'ofile' variable.
2. Run the below script and repeat for each row in the CSV.
3. The csv file contains no headers and has the 'ofile' values - one per row in column A.

Instead of me running this script, and then updating the ofile variable manually, i would like to automate this process.

Thanks in advance.

```
import time
import pysftp 
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import zipfile
import re

ofile = 'abc_'   
oupload = pysftp.Connection(host="xxxx", username="sxx", password="xNxxxx")

d = datetime.utcnow()
unixtime=calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple())

import datetime
month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m")

string = ofile+month+".*\.txt$"

possibleFiles = oupload.listdir("/")
for filename in possibleFiles:
        filedate = re.search(string, filename)
        if filedate:
            newfile = filename


timestamp  = oupload.stat(newfile).st_atime  

if timestamp != unixtime: 

        newtime=unixtime + 1800  
        zipname = ofile+str(newtime)+'.sync.zip'

        create_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) 

        oupload.get(newfile, newfile)
        oupload.close()

        newfilename = ofile+str(newtime)+'.sync' 
        os.rename(newfile, newfilename)


        create_zip.write(newfilename)

        create_zip.close()


else: 

        print "No file found"
```

The CSV file has no headers, and only has filenames in column A. Here is a snippet:

```
filenamec
filename_b
filename_erf
```

Comment: We need to see an example of your csv file and the expected output/result for that example file. Keep it small. A few lines.

Comment: Does it have only one column? Is the separator a comma `,` or a tab `\t`? This info is necessary to properly parse the file.

Comment: It comma delimited - Thanks and just one column. Column A

Comment: Can't you open that file with notepad and post the first few lines? I need to know if there is an header, any comment, etc.

Comment: Hi, it looks exactly like the above, no headers, the above is just a copy paste. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your script in a function first, then you iterate over each line of the csv file, you extract the value you need and assign it the to `ofile` variable.Finally, run the function passing `ofile` as an argument. I can't be more precise since you haven't posted any example of the actual csv, but the implementation should look something like this:

```
import time
import pysftp 
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import zipfile
import re


def myscript(ofile):  
    oupload = pysftp.Connection(host="xxxx", username="sxx", password="xNxxxx")
    d = datetime.utcnow()
    unixtime=calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple())
    month = datetime.now().strftime("%m")
    string = ofile+month+".*\.txt$"

    possibleFiles = oupload.listdir("/")
    for filename in possibleFiles:
            filedate = re.search(string, filename)
            if filedate:
                newfile = filename

    timestamp  = oupload.stat(newfile).st_atime  
    if timestamp != unixtime:
        newtime=unixtime + 1800
        zipname = ofile+str(newtime)+'.sync.zip'
        create_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        oupload.get(newfile, newfile)
        oupload.close()
        newfilename = ofile+str(newtime)+'.sync' 
        os.rename(newfile, newfilename)
        create_zip.write(newfilename)
        create_zip.close()

    else: 
        print "No file found"


mycsv = 'mydocument.csv'

with open(mycsv, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('\n'): #skip empty lines
            ofile = line.strip() #assuming you have only one column
            myscript(ofile)
```

Comment: thanks, the CSV looks like this:  column a - row1: abcefg_ columb a - row 2: abcjjj

Comment: where you have ofile = #extract your variable here  - how do I extract the variable there? Thanks

Comment: I'm also getting this error: "    d = datetime.utcnow()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'datetime' referenced before assignment" Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post at least one line of your csv. I can't suggest any parsing otherwise

Comment: filename_a  this is what is in cell A1 - I can't attach the file in the comments unfortunately. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited the original question and pasted in how the csv file looks. Cheers

Comment: This is the error I get: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'datetime' referenced before assignment"

Comment: With your code yes because you imported datetime twice messing up the namespaces. But I took care of correcting it. If you use the code I posted you should not get that error

Comment: Hi Alec, ahh sorry, bad copy and paste. I made some edits, and now I've got passed that error but now have this:  "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'newfile' referenced before assignment" - referencing this: :timestamp  = oupload.stat(newfile).st_atime

Comment: The error is self-explanatory `'newfile' referenced before assignment` this is the first time in your program that `newfile` appears and the interpreter doesn't know what is it. That means that `if filedate: newfile = filename` does not get executed. Check the logic of your code and consider to add some try/except block to handle exceptions!

Comment: sorry, I am just a tad confused, the script runs through the first row of the csv fine, that error happens when it runs on the second row? Any tips on how to fix? Thanks

Comment: Again, I need to see the csv file, at least the first few lines otherwise cannot help. Open it with notepad, copy the first 5 lines and post them! Bytheway, this is not a coding service, I would like to help you but please contact me in private for that. alec_djinn[at]yahoo[dot]com. StackOverflow is to ask questions, not to solve homework. From the comments you posted I can see you don't know python enough to solve your task, please consider doing some more basic exercise and studying the reference manual.

Comment: fileabc_
filebcd_ 
filecde

Comment: so, your file is one row and 3 columns, each column separated by `_`?

Comment: nope , its one column - 3 rows - pasting direct into comments box seems to put into a single row. the _ is part of the filename, some have it, others don't. Thanks

fileabc_ 
filebcd_ 
filecde